# Ajax / JSON data transfer broken, changing my Unicode data and breaking my CRC calculations

Tags: java, ajax, json, unicode, crc16

I'm a developer for an order-taking web site.  It has a `Tomcat/Java` backend and used `JavaScript` extensively on the browser. My program manages a conversation with our users concerning the large set of data needed by our internal systems to successfully place an order.  All of our conversations use the `HTTPS` protocol.

A while ago we used to accept our form data (a `Struts` application), process it and return it again as a form.  I noticed some data loss errors.  Using an extension of `HttpServletRequestWrapper`, I could see that certain users were *missing* form data.  A line item here and there, and quite distressing.  Our data ought to be unitary.

So in a recent revision that form is being transferred back and forth through an Ajax conversation, using `JSON`.  We convert the form data into a string, create a CRC sum from it and wrap both of these into a carrier `JSON` object.  The other side will extract the form data string, apply the same `CRC` conversion and then compare the two values.  All well and good, but...

I've found that my `CRC` generation depends on whether the data string contains "high-bit" characters -- things that you get by default from programs like `Microsoft Word`, like those fancy double-quote marks surrounding sentences, foreign-language vowels and whatnot.  It seems that the underlying transport mechanism breaks things.

As an example, if I pass back pre-formatted HTML the forward-slashes like

```
</b>
```

get transformed in-process into

```
<\/b>
```

which doesn't checksum the same.  I can check for extra backslashes, but I'm being frustrated by arbitrary reformatting of text by the transport mechanism.

As another example, I have this bit of `JSON` data on the server:

```
    "alt_bill_contact":"ACCT PAY Rocío",
```

(Note the fancy version of "i" in the word.)

It is directly written to the response (`HttpServletResponse.getWriter().write(JSON output string)`).  The next time I can see it is in

```
ServerRequest.ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
        url : ServerRequest.serverUrl,
        data : sendJSON,
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout: 200000,
        async : async,
        cache : false,
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            if(ServerRequest.ajaxRequest != null) {
                ServerRequest.ajaxErrorResponseHandler(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }

            ServerRequest.ajaxRequest = null;
        },
        success : function(response) {

            if(ServerRequest.ajaxRequest != null) {
                ServerRequest.ajaxSuccessResponseHandler(response);
            }

            ServerRequest.ajaxRequest = null;
        }
    });

[snip]
    var something = ServerRequest.ajaxRequest.responseText;
```

and "something" has:

```
    "alt_bill_contact":"ACCT PAY Roc?o"
```

where "?" is one of those characters that display as a black-diamond.  Internally it is a multi-character Unicode.

The `CRC` I'm using on each end is largely the `AnDan CRC software` (I think it is a CRC-16 implementation).  I can't get a good link for it, just some old download pages :-( .

I'm wondering if there is a switch or configuration that lets me handle my Unicode and high-bit characters through `CRC` handling.  Any ideas?

Comment: I guess, your real problem is not the CRC calculation but the underlying transport layers. There seem to be character encoding and escaping issues.

Comment: I am currently having this the same issue and noone get the right answer. How about yours `@Jerome P Mrozak` have you got the solution?